# How much is the similarity between django and symfony2

Tags: python, django, symfony

I know symfony2 and just finished massive web application in it. i love it.
one year back i did django 1.3 but not much.

now we got a client who want to web application in python django.

Now i know the templates , logger etc are same in both.
But i don't know about advnaced topics. can anyone please exlain does these things exist in Django

1. Annotations i.e vaidations, orm , routing using annotations
2. is there in any dependency injection container in django
3. can i use Roles for security. i mean securing ULS , methods for specific users
4. Event handlers like prePersist , PostUpdate for doing things in some entity creation

Comment: I dont know how simillar they are...but Django is great imho...

Answer (score 1):

1. Django had orm in the day it was born. You map you data in [models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/), validate with [validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/validators/) and you 'route' the request through [urlconf](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/).
2. [Yep](https://github.com/ivan-korobkov/python-inject)
3. There is the [auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/) framework inside Django
4. [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/signals/) but for the majority of the things you'll need to do post/pre init/create/edit/delete you can overload the corresponding method of the model, after all the model is class.

Comment: If you want all the features of Doctrine then you might have to use SQLAlchemy instead of the Django orm.